# PostgreSQL Calculating a Consecutive session

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns

I have a very large table that contains 4 columns: 1) the status property of a member has changed to:
online, offline, game_lobby, load_screen 2) the status property of a member has changed from: online, offline, game_lobby, and load_screen 3) a member's ID number and 4)the timestamp of when the status property changed).  I want to calculate the average time all members spend online, which would be the difference between the timestamp of when a state changes from online to offline and the timestamp of when a state changes from offline to online:
[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNgJA.png)

Using the sample linked above, the average calculated would be (01/03/2016 15:32:05 - 01/02/2016 07:18:32 + 03/14/2016 05:46:41 - 03/14/2016 04:09:04
)/2

Here's what I wrote, which gave me a few negative averages calculated for certain members, which can't be right:

```
with sessions as
( select 
    date_trunc('week', sc.occurred_at) as week,
    sc.occurred_at,
    sc.id,
    timestampdiff(second,lag(sc.occurred_at) over (order by sc.id asc, sc.occurred_at),
    sc.occurred_at)/3600 as session
  from state_changes sc
  where
    ((from_state = 'offline' and to_state = 'online') or
     (from_state = 'offline' and to_state = 'online'))
    and occurred_at at time zone 'America/New_york' > '2016-01-01'
)
select week, avg(session), id
from sessions
group by 1,3;
```

I can roll-up the averages into a single value instead of by member, but what I wrote is clearly wrong since a small number of the averages are returning negative. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically interested in the time period between going from `offline->online` and then going back `?->offline`. So the trick is to get only those records in a sub-query and then do the lag over those two. You have some problems with your code in exactly those two issues, see code below. In the main query you then get the average and throw out the `offline->online` row.

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', logout) AS week,
       avg(extract(epoch from logout - login)),  -- in seconds
       id
FROM (
  SELECT lag(occurred_at) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY occurred_at) AS login,
         occurred_at AS logout,
         id,
         to_state
  FROM state_change
  WHERE (from_state = 'offline' or to_state = 'offline')
    AND occurred_at > '2016-01-01') sub
WHERE to_state = 'offline'
GROUP BY 1,3;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! If this answers your question then you should accept is as such by clicking the grey checkmark on the left. You can also vote by using the arrows above and below the number. This is how the site works and it will bring good answers to the attention of other users with similar problems.